# Subtracting depending on an if function in python

Tags: python

Convert the character into its ASCII code

Add the ASCII code to the offset factor calculated in Task 4.

If the result is bigger than 126 then subtract 94 so it is a valid ASCII code.

Convert the result into its equivalent ASCII character.

I need to subtract 44 from an if function but I'm not really sure how to do it. My code so far is:

```
      a = text
      sev=[ ord(x) for x in a ]
      sev= sev + offsetFactor
      if sev>126
      next sev-44
```

Would I use the next function and if not what function would is use?

Comment: `sev` is a list, it isn't clear what you want to accomplish by adding and subtracting numbers to it. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @interjay Sorry I'll edit it but I want to                                               Convert the character into its ASCII code
Add the ASCII code to the offset factor calculated in Task 4. If the result is bigger than 126 then subtract 94 so it is a valid ASCII code. 
Convert the result into its equivalent ASCII character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = "Kitty Bates"
sev=[ ord(x) for x in a ]
S= sum(sev)

while(1):
    try:
        print chr(S)
        break   # will break on valid ASCII

    except:
        S= S-44
```

**output**
**[Click here](https://repl.it/BXab/1)**

```
Ф
```

As per your req

```
a = "Kitty Bates"
sev=[ ord(x) for x in a ]
S= sum(sev)

while(1):
    try:
        if(S>126):
            0/0
        print chr(S)
        break  #will break if ASCII is below 126

    except:
        S= S-44
```

**output**

```
\
```

Comment: Hi @ravichandra the link doesn't work it says error conmnecting

Comment: Its same code mentioned above in online python compiler

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do

```
  a = text
  sev=[ ord(x) + offsetFactor for x in a]
  sev = [ x - 94 for x in sev if x > 126]
```

Comment: Hiya @user2393267 it keeps on coming with invalid syntax with the bracket on the first line.